# Why do Ruby Net::HTTP.get_response and Net::HTTP.new(uri.host).request return different things?

Tags: ruby, net-http

These 2 requests should have the same result, but the first one returns a 200 (OK) and the second one returns a 404 (Not Found). Why is that?

```
require 'net/http'

url = "http://readwrite.com/2013/12/04/google-compute-engine"
uri = URI(url)
Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
#=> #<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>
Net::HTTP.new(uri.host).request(Net::HTTP::Get.new(url))
#=> #<Net::HTTPNotFound 404 Not Found readbody=true>
```

It happens only with some urls. I couldn't figure out the pattern. Here's another example: `http://davidduchemin.com/2014/01/towards-mastery-again/`.

Answer (score 4):

First, let’s compare the two by viewing their actual HTTP requests with tcpdump so we can get an idea for what may be happening:

```
tcpdump -vvASs 0 port 80 and host www.readwrite.com
```

```
# Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)

GET /2013/12/04/google-compute-engine HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Ruby
Host: readwrite.com
```

```
# Net::HTTP.new(uri.host).request(Net::HTTP::Get.new(url))

GET http://readwrite.com/2013/12/04/google-compute-engine HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Ruby
Connection: close
Host: readwrite.com
```

We can see that the second request is incorrectly requesting the full URL (with hostname) as the path. This is because you’re passing `url` to `Net::HTTP::Get.new` which causes `Net::HTTP::Get.new(url).path` to be just what we see above: the full URL with hostname. Instead pass the URI instance (`uri`) to `Net::HTTP::Get.new`:

```
Net::HTTP.new(uri.host).request(Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri))
#=> #<Net::HTTPOK 200 OK readbody=true>
```

And its tcpdump is now effectively the same as the first’s:

```
GET /2013/12/04/google-compute-engine HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Ruby
Host: readwrite.com
Connection: close
```

Comment: I had tried that but it returns NoMethodError: undefined method `empty?' for #<URI::HTTP:0x007fdc8d4c3008>. Nevertheless doing Net::HTTP.new(uri.host).request(Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.path)) works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Also, thanks for suggesting using tcpdump to debug it. It helped a lot in other problems too.